# Modx Discuss extra is redirecting to 404 page

Tags: modx

I installed modx Discuss and configured it and it's system variables all according to the docs but every forum I click on gets redirected to a 404 page. Double checked all the settings everything is correct, FURLs are on the url it's trying to direct to looks right, .htaccess is correct. User permissions/groups are also correct.

What else could be causing a 404 error in the discuss extra?

no errors in Apache or modx logs.

Comment: 404 may means 403 if "403 page id" not specified in system settings. Try to set all error pages to relevant ids in system settings.

Comment: user groups/permissions were double checked and there is a 403 page defined. In fact if the user does not have permissions to the individual boards - the links to them won't even be displayed.

Comment: Are you sure the htaccess rules are correct, especially the Discuss rules from the docs? Maybe if you're running in a subfolder or other conditions, they need to be fixed.

Comment: hi Mark, first thing I checked, but the docs say: "Rewrite rules are not necessary since 1.2.1 (relased on 23rd of July 2013)" & I also do not have any discuss specific rewrite rules in my local dev setup [which does work]